# Lyx with ding symbols in math mode

Tags: symbols, lyx

I want to use \ding symbols inside **a math formula** (math mode) but everytime I try, I get other symbols rather than the symbols I want. For example, when I write `\ding{38}` in a formula I get the symbol `&`. Any suggestion?

Sometimes it will not compile the document and show an error for missing fonts, for example `\ding{170}`.

Comment: Welcome to tex.se! You might need to load the `pifont` package in the LaTeX preamble. Did you load it?

Comment: @scottkosty Yes, I loaded the package. I shows the wrong symbols only whenever I am in Math mode.

Comment: Maybe try `\mbox{\ding{38}}` to leave math mode for this symbol.

Comment: Thanks @Bernard! It worked for me.